# Wait for data to load before instantiating a component

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular 1.5. I have a component embedded in another component as demonstrated below. Problem is that the `data` variable is not yet resolved when angular fires `component-child` and so I get nothing. How do I wait for the variable to be resolved before the child component instantiates.

**html**

```
<component-parent>
     <component-child data="$ctrl.data._id"><\component-child>
</component-parent>
```

**js**

```
this.data = SomeResource.get();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `ng-if`?

```
<component-parent>
     <component-child ng-if="$ctrl.data._id" data="$ctrl.data._id"> </component-child>
</component-parent>
```

Comment: And there I was looking for a complex lifecycle thing! Duh!

Comment: Always keep it simple! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngIf` to defer compiling of the component to when the data loads:

```
Somesource.get().then(function(data) {
    this.makeComponentVisible = true;
});

<component-parent>
    <component-child ng-if="$ctrl.makeComponentVisible" data="$ctrl.data._id"><\component-child>
</component-parent>
```